# Blenrig retargeting BVH motion

Tags: rigging

I want to apply a BVH MOCAP to a Blenrig 5 rig.  I have tried re-targeting the BVH to the Blenrig using Mocap Tools, but can't select the performer rig to retarget.  Does Mocap Tools work with Blenrig?  Is there a better way to apply a BVH to a Blenrig rig?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

OK, worked it out.  In case this helps someone else, shift click Right Mouse to select both rigs shows the targeting fields:

[image]